# How do apps like Path and Instagram tell if contacts are also using the app?

Tags: ios, contacts, instagram

I am interested in building an app that has a Find Friends by contacts function similar to Path's or Instagram's but am not sure how it's done.

I know Path and Instagram upload your address book to their server, but how are they able to tell if a particular contact is also using the app? Does it also upload the user's phone number and thus match by phone numbers?

CLARIFICATION: I do not save email addresses (or any info other than the contact's phone number) in my address book, yet somehow Path and Instagram are able to tell if that phone number belongs to a user on Path / Instagram. How is this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two join points between your address book and theirs:

1. Your e-mail address (and phone number).
2. Your friends address books that contain your e-mail address (and phone number).

Basically, just because you don't have their e-mail address listed doesn't mean they don't have yours listed. They could also filter this "who has your e-mail in their address book" based on the names and/or phone numbers in your address book.

Yes, it could also be joining on phone number. The point here is that there are many ways to join data together, and your phone doesn't have the complete picture of what they have.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I don't think that could be right either. For approach #2, we'd first get a list of all users who have my email in their address book. That works. But now, how does the app know that that user on their database is the same user on my address book?

For #2, there has to be another join between that list of friends (whose address books contain my email) and my address book. But joined by what? I could use a nickname instead of his real name and yet the contact appears.

Comment: A simple google search yields answers to the question of how to do name matching when names on both sides don't precisely match, such as [this article](http://www.omninerd.com/articles/Data_Analytics_Approach_to_Name_Matching)